# Adding global root key and specific root key for each serialized item with active model serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I am using [active-model-serializer](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). I have a collection of objects that I need to return as a JSON in a special formal. Here's what I have written so far:

```
  @tickets = Ticket.where(status: "PLACED")
  render json: @tickets, root: 'placed', each_serializer: ItemSerializer
```

Here's my item serializer:

```
class ItemSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
  attributes :pool_id, :selections

  def root
   "params"
 end
end
```

Here's the response with the current code:

`[{\"pool_id\":759,\"selections\":\"1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8\"}]`

I want to be able to add a root key `"params"` to each element of the array and a global root key `"placed"` before the array, so the desired output would be:

```
{ "placed": [
    {
      "params": {
        "pool_id": 123,
        "selections": "1/1/1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve that with an active model serializer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the global root key, I needed to add `adapter: :json` to the render call

```
render json: @tickets, root: 'placed', each_serializer: BatchItemSerializer, adapter: :json
```

To add a key at the root of each serialized element, you can overwrite the `attributes` method in the serializer. In this specific case, you can do it like this:

```
  def attributes(*args)
    hash = super
    { params: hash }
  end
```